# Custom Views Sort Order Using Filter Value

Tags: 7, views

I have a View containing a list of events.  There is a date field on the event content type which contains start and end time:

[image]

There is a filter for start time, which is setup using the [Views Between Dates Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_between_dates_filter):

[image]

This means that entering `11:00am` in the filter will ensure that the event with time `10:00 AM to 3:00PM` exists in the results since 11 falls between 10 and 3.

The full result set might look like the following when using `11am` for the filter:

```
7am to 3pm
8am to 12pm
9am to 11:30pm
11am to 12:00pm
11am to 1pm
```

How can I create a custom sort, such that the exact matches for start time are ordered first?  These are the results I need:

```
11am to 12:00pm
11am to 1pm
7am to 3pm
8am to 12pm
9am to 11:30pm
```

Is there a way to create a custom sort handler for views using filter values?

EDIT: I'd hoped I could use `hook_views_post_execute` to re-order the data but I'm using a pager, so only the first 10 results exist in `$view->result`

Comment: In views sort criteria did u try to sort using start date?

Comment: Start date would give me my first set of results (7, 8, 9, 11, 11), whereas I need a non-sequential order (11, 11, 7, 8, 9)

Comment: why 7 after 11? What kind of order you are trying to do asc or desc? If you want custom order, then add a separate field for ordering purposes only.. For example just add one more field name as Weight, then you can use that field in views for sorting. Otherwise try a traditional approach by using [Nodequeue](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodequeue) module.

Comment: It's based on the value the user chooses in the filter.  I.e. if the user chooses 11 in the filter then we want 11 first.  I came to the same conclusion as you mentioned, the only solution is to store data in fields since views relies on SQL for sorting.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, my client agreed this feature was overkill and it was ommitted but I thought of a way it could be achieved.

**Potential Solution**

The following is only feasible if you have a finite and relatively low number of filter values because you need to create a field for every filter value.

- Create a field of type boolean for every filter value.  In our case we had `10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3` as potential values for hour and `00, 15, 30, 45` for minute.  24 possible combinations, so 24 fields need added to the event type.
- The field should be named according to the filter combination, e.g. `Sort: 10:00`, `Sort: 10:15` etc.
- The field value should be set as either `1` or `0`.  If the event start time matches the time in the name of sort field then this should be set to `1` otherwise it should be set to `0`.  `hook_node_insert` and `hook_node_update` could be used to set the values.

E.g on each event you would have:

```
Start Time - 11:00

Sort 10:00 - 0
Sort 10:15 - 0
Sort 10:30 - 0
Sort 10:45 - 0
Sort 11:00 - 1
etc (the rest would be set to 0).
```

- When the filter is applied, use `hook_views_query_alter` to grab the filter value.  Then set the sort based on that field.

E.g if the user entered `11:00` as the filter value, we could force the sort to use the `Sort: 11:00` field.  The following is written off the top of my head, so would need some tweaks:

```
function my_module_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  if($view->exposed_input['field_start_time'][0]['value'] == "11:00am") {
    $view->query->orderby[0]['field'] = "field_data_field_sort_11_00_value";
    $view->query->orderby[0]['direction'] = "DESC";
    // Add any secondary sorts.
  }
  else if($view->exposed_input['field_start_time'][0]['value'] == "11:15am") {
    $view->query->orderby[0]['field'] = "field_data_field_sort_11_15_value";
    $view->query->orderby[0]['direction'] = "DESC";
    // Add any secondary sorts.
  }
}
```